# Validate list object is unique

Tags: validation, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF. I got a below requirement:

1) Have a complex object Department location list with each department carrying Employees designation list. Have another two lists: object department names and employee names. All the objects are dynamic based on the data in the table.

2) I have to display departments locations as multiple table and employees designation in each row of it based on the complex object. I also have to provide drop down list of department name as header of each table header and drop down list near each employee designation with employee name.

3) The user now has to select the right name to employee designation and department location.

---- To perform this I have used an iterator and used tablelayout. Placed the dropdown in each row and it is working sweet.---

********* Now the client need me to do a validation to check non duplicate value is selected. 
Meaning no 2 department have same name as well, no 2 employee carry same name. They want me to either disable the already selected name in other drop downs (or) if it is not possible validate the form before submitting and highlighted the duplicate select box.*********

Since I am using the iterator and placing the select box in dynamic manner I am not able to use the PPR, more over I can't use the PPR for SELECT ITEM.

Please help me on doing validation or disable already selected name.

Sample table:

---

```
| DEP LOC 1 | dropdown list  |
______________________________
|emp 1      | dropdown list  |
______________________________
|emp 2      | dropdown list  |
______________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting dropdown values from VO then you can add a transient attribute in that VO, which can contain 1/0 or true/false to indicate if the value has already been selected. You can set this indicator whenever a value is selected from a dropdown and then use it later to avoid duplicate selections.